# Why is the Indominus Rex called this way?

Tags: jurassic-world

I have a question about *Jurassic World*. Why was the Indominus Rex called Indominus Rex when "indominus rex" means "untamable king" and it's clearly stated that the Indominus Rex was female, which would have made it indominus regina, which means untamable queen.

Comment: Precisely because of the nature of what it actually was, that is an artificially created *product* with the sole purpose of *entertainment and marketing*. Noone really cares if it's a rex or a regina, people want a cool name instead and its creators are free to pick whatever name they want. They didn't obey nature with the creature itself, so they don't have to follow it with its name either.

Comment: Though, I have another question for you, what's a female Tyrannosaurus Rex called? ;-)

Comment: Hm you have a point thank you for answering my question it's been on my mind ever since I watched the movie and on your question to me I guess it would still be trex since nobody actually cared if it was a he or a she as long as it had big teeth they would be to busy running the other way to turn around and see if they should come up with another name for it lol

Answer (score 4):

In universe it's clearly because it's supposed to be an improvement on tyrannosaurus Rex.

Out of universe, the name is literary foreshadowing. It's a significant name trope. Indomitable, they try to capture and control it. They fell. Irony 101.

As to the Rex part, this is rooted in modern english preference of male as the default gender. **The species is called Rex, while the individual could be either gender.** Mankind, male in female, etc. The T-Rex from the first movie which also shows up in Jurassic World is also female, but still referred to as T-Rex, not regina.

Of course, the proper name would be Indomina Regina, not Indominus Regina. The Indominus would also change suffix on a gender change.

Comment: Indomina Regina just doesn't sound terrifying enough.